# Acceleration at rest when ball is thown

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

If a ball is thrown vertically upward and it comes to rest for a moment, then its velocity decreases and becomes zero. Does its acceleration also becomes zero? If yes then how ball falls down?

Comment: Why would the acceleration also be zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an object's instantaneous speed be zero and it's instantaneous acceleration be nonzero?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34178/)

Answer (score 0):

When the ball is travelling in your hand before you let go, it is being accelerated by the amount of force you exert on it, this increases its velocity before you let go. (The initial velocity)

When you let go of the ball, it immediately begins to slow down due to the acceleration of gravity acting downwards. There is no upwards acceleration, as this stopped the moment you let go of the ball.

(There is no point in the ball's flight where there is no acceleration acting on it.)

Eventually, the acceleration due to gravity will make it so that the upwards velocity of all ball reaches zero. This is instantaneous. Only the velocity reaches zero however, the value of the acceleration stays the same.

The only change to the acceleration is its direction relative to the direction of the movement of the ball: When the ball is traveling down, it points in the direction of movement.  At all times the acceleration points down. This is why the ball speeds up as it is falling back down.

I hope this answers your question!